# Is it true that $n> a^2\Rightarrow n!>a^n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}, a\in\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: factorial, exponentiation

If so, how can it be proven? (I have evaluated it up to $n=25$.)

If not, does there exist a $k\in\mathbb{R}$ such as that $n> a^k\Rightarrow n!>a^n$, with $n\in\mathbb{N},a\in\mathbb{R}$?

---

It is true, and to prove it, it suffices to show that $n!^2\geq n^n$ with induction.

For $n=1$ we have that $1\geq1$, which is true. Suppose $n!^2\geq n^n$. Then, $(n+1)!^2=(n+1)^2n!^2\geq (n+1)^2n^n$. We need to show that

$$\begin{align}
&(n+1)^2n^n\geq (n+1)^{n+1}\Leftrightarrow\\
\Leftrightarrow &n^n \geq (n+1)^{n-1}\Leftrightarrow\\
\Leftrightarrow &\ln(n^n)\geq \ln((n+1)^{n-1})\Leftrightarrow\\
\Leftrightarrow &n\ln n\geq (n-1)\ln(n+1)\Leftrightarrow\\
\Leftrightarrow &\frac{n}{n-1} \geq \ln(n+1-n)=\ln1=0\quad,
\end{align}$$

which is true!!

Comment: I imagine you can work out the answer. The key is [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)  If you do work it out, you should consider posting the answer yourself. (Yes, that is not only allowed, it is encouraged.)

Comment: It's true; it's a consequence of the fact that $n!^2\ge n^n$. As for how that's proved, perhaps I'll leave that unstated for now...

Comment: I proved $n!^2\geq n^n$ with induction.For $n=1$ we have that $1\geq1$ which is true. Suppose $n!^2\geq n^n$. Then, $(n+1)!^2=(n+1)^2n!^2\geq (n+1)^2n^n$.  We need to show that $(n+1)^2n^n\geq (n+1)^{n+1}\Leftrightarrow (n+1)n^n\geq (n+1)^n\Leftrightarrow n^n \geq (n+1)^{n-1}$ $\Leftrightarrow \ln(n^n)\geq \ln((n+1)^{n-1})\Leftrightarrow n\ln n\geq \(n-1)\ln(n+1)$ $\Leftrightarrow  \frac{n}{n-1} \geq \ln(n+1-n)=ln1=0$ which is true!! How could I use the Stirling's approximation to get a similar result??

Answer (score 2):

Converting above realization to an answer.

---

We prove $ \left( n! \right)^2 \ge n^n $ by means of induction.

For $n=1$, we have $ 1 \ge 1 $, which is true. Now suppose that $ \left( n! \right)^2 \ge n^n $. Then, $$ \begin {align*} \left( (n+1)! \right)^2 &= \left( n + 1 \right)^2 \left( n! \right)^2 \\&\ge \left( n + 1 \right)^2 n^n. \end {align*} $$Furthermore, $$ \begin {eqnarray*} \left( n+1 \right)^2 n^n &\ge& (n+1)^{n+1} \\ \iff \left( n + 1 \right) n^n &\ge& (n+1)^n \\ \iff n^n &\ge& (n+1)^{n-1} \\ \iff \ln \left( n^n \right) &\ge& \ln \left( \left( n + 1 \right)^{n-1} \right) \\ \iff n \ln n &\ge& \left( n - 1 \right) \cdot \ln \left( n + 1 \right) \\ \iff \frac {n}{n-1} &\ge& \ln \left( n + 1 - n \right) = \ln 1 = 0, \end {eqnarray*} $$ which is true, so we are done. $\Box$